# Configure JMX with Spring implementation of ehcache?

Tags: spring, ehcache, jmx

I'm trying to follow the articles [here](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/How-to-monitor-Ehcache-in-JMX-with-Spring-Configuration) &  [here](http://2mohitarora.blogspot.com/2012/01/monitoring-ehcache-with-jmx-and-spring.html) to implement JMX for ehCache.  My app uses the Spring implementation however & the config entries below get this exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'managementService' defined in class
>   path resource [trs.application.finance.businessactivites.xml]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager]: Could not convert
>   constructor argument value of type
>   [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] to required
>   type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager]: Failed to convert value of type
>   'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager' to required
>   type 'net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] to required
>   type [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager]: no matching editors or conversion
>   strategy found

Does spring have an implementation of net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService I can use?  If so how do I configure it so I can have JMX support for ehcache in my app.

Note, the "managementService" & "mbeanServer" beans are what I added to try & get ehcache to register with jmx. "myCacheManager" already exists in my spring config & seems to work fine, as far ehcache alone goes.

```
 <bean id="managementService" class="net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService"
      init-method="init"
      destroy-method="dispose">
    <constructor-arg ref="myCacheManager"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="mbeanServer"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="true"/>
    <constructor-arg index="3" value="true"/>
    <constructor-arg index="4" value="true"/>
    <constructor-arg index="5" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
      <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="myCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you wire your beans.

You do not want to use `myCacheManager` in the `managementService`, you really want to use the bean returned and passed as the `cacheManager` of `myCacheManager`.

So I suggest moving the following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

to a top level bean so that it can be injected in `managementService`.